# replacing javascript slide show buttons with images files, not working for me

Tags: javascript, button, slideshow

how would i change the back forward & stop buttons on this slide show to image file ? any time i've tried , the image files dont work correctly as buttons ( i followed the instructions on the w3 site ....

```
<DIV align="center">
              <INPUT type=button onClick="Oneprevious();" value="<<" title="Previous">
              <INPUT type=button name="Oneslidebutton" onClick="Oneap(this.value);" value="Start" title="AutoPlay">
              <INPUT type=button onClick="Onenext();" value=">>" title="Next">
      </DIV>
```

this didnt work for me `<input type="image" src="submit.gif" alt="Submit" />` , i'd severely appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<div align="center">
     <img src="previous.jpg" onclick="Oneprevious();" title="Previous">
     <img src="play.jpg" onclick="Oneap('Start');" title="Play">
     <img src="next.jpg" onclick="Onenext();" title="Next">
</div>
```